# Internet Explorer stops calling JavaScript event handlers on user action after a first form submit

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, events, iframe

The event handlers are assigned inline in HTML source `('onclick="..."')`.  That HTML source is received in an iframe and moved to the shown page `(document.getElementById("...").appendChild(iframenodesnewhtmlsource)).`

The event handlers do a `form submit (document.getElementById("form1").submit())`. The form is submitted to the iframe the new HTML source from above was received in. The `"action="` page of the form responds by sending an HTML page which does a `parent.func()` in its JavaScript. These `parent.func()` are functions in the shown page in the same scope as the event handlers and are executed: Implicit JavaScript is still executed after a form submit.

Doing an action on the event handlers element again which should call the event handler does not call the event handler however: Explicit JavaScript event handlers are not called after a form submit.

A naming conflict in IE resulted in the same issue with similar code: IE doesn't like form names like "form" or ids which have the same name as a function or something like this. If you don't have a solution to the original issue, write about IEs HTML element naming and JavaScript naming do s if you know them.

HTML5, Internet Explorer 8 Standards Mode.

Code following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callback(data,type)
        {
            if(type == 0)
            {
                if(document.getElementById("tablediv").firstChild != null)
                {
                    document.getElementById("tablediv").removeChild(document.getElementById("tablediv").firstChild);
                }
                document.getElementById("tablediv").appendChild(data.firstChild);
            }
        }

        function load(tablesrc)
        {
            document.getElementById("changedfield").value = "table";

            document.getElementById("showntable").value = tablesrc + "";
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }

        function savevalue(src,node)
        {
            document.getElementById("changedfield").value = src.id;
            document.getElementById("changedvalue").value = src.value;

            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }
        function init()
        {
            document.getElementById("form1").setAttribute("action","/cgi-bin"+window.location.pathname.substring(0,window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/../../gettable.cgi");
            load(1);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:init()">
    <div id="tables">
        <form id="form0" name="form0">
            <div id="tableselect">
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(1)" />
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(2)" />
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(3)" />
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(4)" />
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(5)" />
                <input type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:load(6)" />
            </div>
            <div id="tablediv"></div>
        </form>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" target="iframe1" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" id="showntable" name="showntable" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" id="changedfield" name="changedfield" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" id="changedvalue" name="changedvalue" value="" />
        </form>
        <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```